# Charge shipping based on discount code

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, shopping-cart-price-rules, discount

Our store has blanket free shipping in the UK, and flat rate shipping elsewhere.

I need to create a shopping cart rule (discount code) for 50% off everything, but I also need that code to trigger the shipping to be chargable.

So let's say the cart is £100 with free shipping, the user enters a 50% discount code, the new total would be £50cart + £5 shipping.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

See if this works out:

1. Setup a shopping cart rule that gives the free shipping for UK and set it's priority so that it's the last rule evaluated
2. Set up another shopping cart rule that gives the 50% coupon discount and set it's priority so that it's the second to last rule evaluated
3. On the 50% coupon discount rule set the **Stop Further Rules Processing** flag to **yes**

This should prevent the free shipping rule from being evaluated so the users will get charged the shipping fees.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this feature try to search module on connect which allows to add surcharge to subtotal. You will have one default rule with discount. Your second rule will have surcharge (your additional 5 pounds). I tried to find some one, but all of them not free. You can check their demo pages.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalogsearch/result/?q=surcharge&pl=0

**Upd.1**

For example one extension can add surcharge like this:

[image]

Sure you can rename this field. And this surcharge adding automatically, like price rule. I'm not sure it is configured also there.

*Or maybe you'd like to add two rules in one row?*

**Upd.2**

For example following extension:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/surcharge-or-additional-fee.html

4) This can be used **for additional shipping fee** or import duty or surcharge or service charge or any other additional fee

5) Additional fees can be added as **fixed amount** or percentage

**Upd.3**

I think this can suite you.
Configure your **Flat rate** shipping method:

[image]

Your method name will be 'Freeshiping' (not flat rate)
Put fixed amount per order.

Comment: This was my thought too, but unfortunately there doesn't seem to be one that can tie it to a shopping cart rule/discount code.

Comment: I've updated my post

Comment: Yeah that doesn't really cover it though.  It's tied to a discount code, so someone enters code `abc123` at checkout, and at this point it needs to apply a surcharge to cover postage.  None of the surcharge extensions seem to allow it to be tied to a shopping cart rule.

Comment: I think you can find described extension. One of the examples you can find in Upd.2 section

Comment: I have one more idea!!!

Comment: But it's not for every order, only for orders that have a very specific discount code applied

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. I would extend whatever module you are using to calculate shipping in a custom module that rewrites the shipping logic to check for the presence of your discount coupon and then apply or not apply the UK shipping flat rate.